# How to shift a column in pandas dataframe group and then join back to be a single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

if I have a dataframe like this:

```
category name index 
A        A11   1
A        A12   1
A        A13   1
A        A21   2
A        A22   2
A        A23   2
...
B        B11   1
B        B21   2
...
```

I want to first group the dataframe by the category and index, and inside each group I want to shift the `name` column by the value of index (reversed shifting) - 1.

So the result would be like:

```
category name index 
A        A11   1    # Do not shift anything because index is 1
A        A12   1
A        A13   1
A        A22   2    # Shift -1 for anything in (A, 2) group because index here is 2
A        A23   2
A        A24   2
...
B        B11   1
B        NA    2  # at the end of each group it should be NA
```

I have tried to use .groupby() and then .apply() but it seems that there is no easy way to join the result back to the dataframe. It seems that the apply method can only return a series. How could I achieve this using the apply method?

Comment: Is this a roll, so that `A21` goes to the end of the group? The shift is by index-1?

Comment: I think its more like a groupby and substract index to the numerical part of name

Comment: @ALollz updated the question. It is a shift by -1 for 2, shift -2 for 3 etc.

Comment: @yatu could you be more specific?

Comment: But what happens at the end of the groups? Should the values be wrapped around, like in a `roll` or are they filled with `NaN`? You haven't shown enough information to infer that.

Comment: @ALollz should be NA I added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question

```
l=[y.assign(name=y.name.shift(-x[1]+1).values) for x , y in df.groupby(['category','index'])]

Newdf=pd.concat(l)
Newdf
Out[644]: 
  category name  index
0        A  A11      1
1        A  A12      1
2        A  A13      1
3        A  A23      2
4        A  A24      2
5        A  NaN      2
```

Comment: I am not saying this is a bad answer at all but this is using a for loop basically. I have thought of doing so but was stuck in trying to come up with a group_by, apply magic

Comment: @dorafmon apply always have bad performance , do not all ways think for loop is bad , check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Answer (score 0):

One way I think you can do this, if I understand correctly:

Given df,

```
  category name  index
0        A  A11      1
1        A  A12      1
2        A  A13      1
3        A  A21      2
4        A  A22      2
5        A  A23      2
6        B  B11      1
7        B  B21      2
```

Use query to filter where index is not 1, then shift within `groupby` and concat part of filter dataframe where index equals 1 to shifted dataframe.

```
df_shifted = (df.query("index > 1").groupby(['category','index'])
                                   .apply(lambda x: x['name'].shift(-1))
                .reset_index().set_index('level_2').rename_axis(None))

df_out = pd.concat([df_shifted, df.query("index == 1")], sort=False).sort_index()
df_out
```

Output:

```
  category  index name
0        A      1  A11
1        A      1  A12
2        A      1  A13
3        A      2  A22
4        A      2  A23
5        A      2  NaN
6        B      1  B11
7        B      2  NaN
```